# Adding external 3D(.OBJ & .MTL) Objects to ARToolkit

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, artoolkit, android-augmented-reality

I have been working on the ARToolkit sdk for android since some time.

In the ARToolkit SDK, I have worked on ARBaseLib and ARSimpleNativeCarsProj and implemented successfully. But I am trying to add external 3d Objects(.obj and .mtl) and I am unable to render the new object files.

I have also looked into the source code provided in this link,
https://github.com/kosiara/artoolkit-android-studio-example
but the problem here is the 3D object(Cube) has been created in using the draw(), openGL libraries function, instead i would want to add an external 3D Object.

More Explanation: 
Okey, SimpleNativeCarsProj comes along with two 3D Objects(.OBJ and .MTL) in the assets/Data folder. **CASE1** I tried replacing the existing 3Dobject with another 3D Objects, App Crashes on the launch **CASE2** As I worked around a little, these files are pushed to the cache folder on the app load, I invalidated the caches and restarted android studio, rebuilt and ran the app, still the app crashes on the launch. Technically I am unable to Replace/Delete/Add another 3D Object files to SimpleNativeCarsProject

Any headsup would be appreciated.

Comment: As you already know how the SimpleNativeCarsProj works I wonder if you could give me some more details what you mean by loading external 3D objects? And if you could provide some insights into your project structure.

Comment: Okey, SimpleNativeCarsProj  comes along with two 3D Objects(.OBJ and .MTL) in the assets/Data folder. **CASE1** I tried replacing the existing 3Dobject with another 3D Objects, App Crashes on the launch **CASE 2** As I worked around a little, these files are pushed to the cache folder on the app load, I invalidated the caches and restarted android studio, rebuilt the app and ran the app, still the app crashes on the launch. **Technically I am unable to Replace/Delete/Add another 3D Object files to SimpleNativeCarsProject**

Comment: Have a look here at his project. She successfully added other obj files and markers. Maybe that helps: https://github.com/sophiemoerman/ARSimpleNativeCars

Answer (score 0):

Convert your FBX files

The Encoder works wit FBX (.fbx) files. We recommend using FBX wherever possible as tools support for FBX is widely available.

http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk-features/wikitude-3d-encoder/

Comment: So you suggest me not to use ARToolkit or ARToolkit allows FBX files ?

Comment: Using FBX or using wikitude is not an option for me, I'm keenly looking in to ARtoolkit implementation. Thanks for the option anyway !!

Comment: I have used ARToolkit with Three js in Cordoba. Slow for lack of support for opengl.

Answer (score 0):

Give [ArToolKitJpctBaseLib](https://github.com/plattysoft/ArToolKitJpctBaseLib) a try. It is a wrapper on ArToolKit + jPCT-AE (a 3d Engine on Android) aims to simplify creation of AR apps for Android.